# Ubuntu Server Port 443 closed, Docker application not accessible in local network

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, docker

I am using Ubuntu Server Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS in my homelab (esx Server) to test some docker applications. First of all I was testing Bitwarden, a webbased Password-Manger. Without any success. I could not reach the bitwarden page in my local network. Then I installed a brand new ubuntu server to test Keeweb, also an webbased Password-Manager. Installed with docker too, everything with a tutorial. But I cant access the keeweb page over my network.
With `nc -zv 192.168.0.137 443 Connection to 192.168.0.137 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!`  I can see that the port 443 is open. But when I try https://192.168.0.137 from any other system in my local network it doesnt work. I dont belive that there is any problem in my local network, because I also running a Windows VM with the PRTG monitoring system, and I can reach that webpage through my local netwok.

Powershell says that the port 443 and 80 is not open. UFW was disabled at the beginning, but for testing purposes I enabled it an set up some rules that supposed to allow everything:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

My docker container is also running:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                                  NAMES
625e33e7d24d   antelle/keeweb   "/opt/entrypoint.sh …"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   192.168.0.137:80->80/tcp, 192.168.0.137:443->443/tcp   keeweb
```

and run by:

```
sudo docker run --name keeweb  -d -p 192.168.0.137:443:443 -p 192.168.0.137:80:80 antelle/keeweb
```

At my first try, I didnt set up the 192.168.0.137, it was just the ports.

This is the iptables output:

```
sudo iptables -L -t nat
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !localhost/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:https
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             bitwarden-2          tcp dpt:https to:172.17.0.2:443
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             bitwarden-2          tcp dpt:http to:172.17.0.2:80
```